# Streaming Subtitles with VLC

Tags: video-streaming

I'm trying to stream from an `*.mkv` file over HTTP using VLC. The file has a soft-coded subtitle set, and I'd like to pass that along with the stream without having to burn in the subtitles or extract them and stream them separately or whatever. The obvious solution - just setting `mux=mkv` and trying to directly forward the file - doesn't seem to work, however.

I'd rather not transcode if I don't have to; the file is compressed and my computer is nothing impressive, so as it is I already have a certain degree of shoddy playback.

Comment: Okay, so I realize this isn't perfectly on-topic, but I had no idea where to put it, so instead of just voting to close could you give me some advice? This doesn't seem on-topic for SuperUser or Webmaster either.

Comment: Maybe adding some language tags or opening a bounty brings more attention to the question.